# Adding Polynomials Through Linked Lists

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I'm writing code that takes two sets of polynomials from the user through a struct class:

```
struct Term
{
    double coefficient;
    unsigned exponent;
    Term *next;
};
```

And then prompts to ask them to add, subtract, or evaluate (asks the user for a value for "x") the polynomials. I'm having trouble with writing the add and subtract function. I wrote this so far for the add function, but I'm not sure how to return the new polynomial. From my understanding from the error message, I can't use the += operator with type `TermPtr`. I'm not sure how to get around this.

```
TermPtr add(TermPtr p1, TermPtr p2)
{   
    TermPtr newPoly;

    if (p1 -> exponent == p2 -> exponent)
          newPoly += ((p1 -> coeff) + (p2 -> coeff));

    return newPoly;
}
```

I get these errors:

```
In function 'Term* add(TermPtr, TermPtr)':
36:19: error: invalid operands of types 'TermPtr {aka Term*}' and 'double' to binary 'operator+'
36:19: error:   in evaluation of 'operator+=(using TermPtr = struct Term* {aka struct Term*}, double)'
```

Comment: your signature wants two term pointers, and you're calling with a term pointer and a double value. You need to provide an operator+ overload for (TermPtr, double).

Answer (score 1):

Since TermPtr is a typedef to Term*, your code is trying to increment a pointer. If you want to return a pointer, then the following code should do the trick, but returning a pointer to the new term means that you'll have to manage the memory manually and delete it later, or leak memory.

```
 TermPtr add(TermPtr p1, TermPtr p2)
    {   
        TermPtr newPoly = new Term();
        newPoly -> exponent = p1 -> exponent;
        if (p1 -> exponent == p2 -> exponent){
              newPoly -> coeff += ((p1 -> coeff) + (p2 -> coeff));
        }


        return newPoly;
    }
```

Keep in mind that if the exponents don't match, you'll still end up with a new term (with coefficient equal to 0, assuming your default constructor assigns 0 to coeff).

What you probably wanted to do is something like this:

```
Term add(TermPtr p1, TermPtr p2)
{   
    Term newPoly;
    newPoly.exponent = p1 -> exponent;
    if (p1 -> exponent == p2 -> exponent){
          newPoly.coeff += ((p1 -> coeff) + (p2 -> coeff));
    }


    return newPoly;
}
```

This way you don't have to manage the memory yourself later on.

As for the general idea, you might want to check the exponents before calling the add, so as not to end up with empty terms.